# Java 8 - Stream - refer composite objects

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<Entry> entries`, with below code structure,

```
class Entry {
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
}

class Product {

    public List<CategoriesData> getCategories() {
        return categoriesData;
    }
}

class CategoriesData {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I'm looking at sorting by Product - CategoriesData - name (from the first element in `List<CategoriesData>`)

```
// Not sure how to refer Name within CategoriesData, 
// entries.stream().sorted(
//   Comparator.comparing(Entry::getProduct::getCategories::getName))
//                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Alright, not sure what kind of comparison would that be, but you can achieve it using `Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getProduct().getCategories().get(0).getName())`.

Comment: `.get(0)` , you sure?? It is not good practice :p

Comment: @Naman I'm getting 'The method getProduct() is undefined for the type Object' error, what could be the reason?

Comment: @SyAu hopefully you have a stream of entries as in the question and then it shouldn't really end up with the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With input from @Mureinik and making some modifications, I ended up with below and it is working. My requirement slightly changed, I need result in a map. Category name is the key in the map, value will be a list of 'Entry'.

```
 final Map<String, List<Entry>> sortedMap =
        data.getEntries().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> ((Entry) e).getProduct().getCategories().stream().findFirst().get().getName())
               .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(e -> ((Entry) e).getProduct().getName())) )
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getProduct().getCategories().stream().findFirst().get().getName(),
                 LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sort by the first category, you need to refer to it in the comparator:

```
List<Entry> sorted = 
    entries.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                                  e -> e.getProduct().getCategories().get(0).getName())
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, for a secondary sorting, you'll have to specify the type in the `Comparator`:

```
List<Entry> sorted = 
    entries.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                                  e -> e.getProduct().getCategories().get(0).getName())
                             .thenComparing(
                                  (Entry e) -> e.getProduct().getName())
           .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting error with that 'The method getProduct() is undefined for the type Object' . 'Entry' got 'getProduct' method, but it's throwing error.

Comment: @SyAu What type is `entries`?

Comment: 'entries' is an array list of 'Entry' objects

Comment: @SyAu Make you are collecting the result in a `List<Entry>` as well as in the answer. Given, that's an unknown in the question.

Comment: @Mureinik I tested sorting by category name and it worked. Now I wanted to add one more sorting field,  Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getProduct().getCategories().stream().findFirst().get().getName())
     .thenComparing(e -> e.getProduct().getName()))    , this is throwing error.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks for your time, I solved my problem, please see my post.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mureinik solution you can do:

```
Comparator<Entry> entryComperator = Comparator
                .comparing(e -> e.getProduct().getCategories().get(0).getName());
        List<Entry> sorted =
                entries.stream()
                        .sorted(entryComperator)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might consider accessing the name from the list better in case the list is empty. you can hide all this logic in the comparator like I did above